# Make The Overflow newsletter dark mode friendly

Tags: feature-request, dark-mode, the-overflow

Is there a way The Overflow can be made to be dark mode friendly? Every time I open it at night the bright white and gray background blinds me. I've received other HTML emails where email clients are able to successfully change the background to match the system setting.

Comment: Possible workaround: https://darkreader.org/

Comment: Oh I definitely use dark reader extensions for browsers on my laptop and my phone. Not sure how I lived without them. Unfortunately they don't apply to standalone email clients.

Comment: I think this FR can be marked status-completed.

Comment: @bad_coder Why should it be marked completed? I just tested and it's still as white as can be in dark mode in my email client.

Comment: @Billy ohh my mistake, I probably mistook the Blog itself for the newsletter.